# How to hide webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd file?

Tags: web-application, webserver

I am getting an email from the security team, saying that webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd are visible. How do I hide it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems more  to fit in stack overflow.

However you can remove those files by adding following to all my web.config files

```
<httpHandlers>
        <remove path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET"/>
        <remove path="WebResource.axd" verb="POST"/>
        <remove path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET"/>
        <remove path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="POST"/>
 </httpHandlers>
```

Now when you try to get these pages you might be prompted to login or given 404 error.

Also remove them from  in

```
<system.webServer> 
     <handlers>
         <remove name="ScriptResourceIntegrated-4.0"/>
     </handlers>
</system.webServer> 

<location path="WebResource.axd">
 <system.web> 
<authorization>
 <deny users="*"/>
 </authorization> 
</system.web> 
</location>
```

Comment: **<location path="WebResource.axd">
    <system.web>    
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>**

//I can prevent public access to **WebResource.axd** file by using the above line of code in webconfig file.

//But i am unable to do the same for **ScriptResource.axd**

Comment: please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856991/removing-unused-http-handlers-for-better-performance-security/29060020. Also try URL rewriting.

Comment: <system.webServer>
<handlers>
 <remove name="ScriptResourceIntegrated-4.0"/>
    </handlers>
 </system.webServer> above lines worked for me to prevent public access to ScriptResource.axd

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Add this as well 
<location path="WebResource.axd"> <system.web> <authorization> <deny users="*"/> </authorization> </system.web> </location>

Comment: If you do this, will the functionality of the web application suffer?